# Next-generation matrix of infectious disease

Tags: mathematical-modeling, epidemics-modeling

If the population is classified into $\mathbf{S}$, $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ compartments such that
\begin{equation}
\label{eq4}
\begin{aligned}
   \mathbf{S} &=\dfrac{S_{1}N_{1}+S_{2}N_{2}+ \dotsb  + S_{k}N_{k}}{N_{1}+N_{2}+\dots +N_{k}} = \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{k} S_{n} N_{n}  \nonumber \\
  \mathbf{E} &=\dfrac{E_{1}N_{1}+E_{2}N_{2}+ \dotsb  + E_{k}N_{k}}{N_{1}+N_{2}+\dots +N_{k}} = \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{k} E_{n} N_{n}   \nonumber \\
   \mathbf{I} &=\dfrac{I_{1}N_{1}+I_{2}N_{2}+ \dotsb  + I_{k}N_{k}}{N_{1}+N_{2}+\dotsb +N_{k}}  = \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{k} I_{n} N_{n} \nonumber \\
  \mathbf{R} &=\dfrac{R_{1}N_{1}+R_{2}N_{2}+ \dotsb  + R_{k}N_{k}}{N_{1}+N_{2}+\dotsb +N_{k}}  = \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{k} R_{n} N_{n} .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The total normalized  population of a region (state) or country is  given by
\begin{equation} \label{eq5} \mathbf{S}+\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{R}=1
\end{equation}
The dynamics of SEIR epidemic spreading model that describe the transmission of disease  in a population without demography in one region is given by the  following system of  differential equations  :
\begin{align}  \label{eq6} 
    \dfrac{d\mathbf{S}}{dt}&= - \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{k}  \left[ \mathbb{S} \mathbb{K}_{\kappa \lambda}   \right]_{n} N_{n} \mathbf{I}  \nonumber \\
     \dfrac{d\mathbf{E}}{dt}&=\dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{k}  \left[ \mathbb{S} \mathbb{K}_{\kappa \lambda}  \right]_{n} N_{n} \mathbf{I}  - \frac{1}{T_{inc.}} \mathbf{E}  \nonumber \\
      \dfrac{d \mathbf{I}}{dt}&= \frac{1}{T_{inc.}} \mathbf{E}  -\frac{1}{T_{inf.}} \mathbf{I}   \nonumber \\
      \dfrac{d \mathbf{R}}{dt}&=  \frac{1}{T_{inf.}} \mathbf{I}
\end{align}
Where $\mathbb{S}=diag(S_{1},\dots,S_{k})$ and $\mathbb{K}_{\kappa \lambda}$ is $(k\times k)$  mobility infectiousness matrix, with $\mathbf{N}=\mathbf{S}+\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{R}=1$ such that $\mathbf{N}=(N_{1},\dots,N_{k})^T$ and initial condition of dynamics
\begin{align}\label{eq7}
   \mathbf{S_{0}}&=\dfrac{S^0_{1}N_{1} +S^0_{2}N_{2} + \dots S^0_{k}N_{K} }{N} , ~~~` \mathbf{E_{0}}=\dfrac{E^0_{1}N_{1} +E^0_{2}N_{2} + \dots E^0_{k}N_{K} }{N} \nonumber \\  
\mathbf{I_{0}}&=\dfrac{I^0_{1}N_{1} +I^0_{2}N_{2} + \dots I^0_{k}N_{K} }{N}, ~~~~ \mathbf{R_{0}}=\dfrac{R^0_{1}N_{1} +R^0_{2}N_{2} + \dots R^0_{k}N_{K} }{N} 
\end{align}

Since the  $\mathbf{S}$, $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ compartments  are scalar by above formula,
and the family mobility infectiousness $ \left[ \mathbb{S} \mathbb{K}_{\kappa \lambda} \right]$ is $k\times k$ matrix, I don't know how to determine the next-generation matrix of this dynamics. Please, I need help!

Comment: If you're using the next-generation matrix to find $R_0$, it may be possible to find a formula $R_0$ using induction.

Comment: What do you mean? Your differential equations make sense only if you view $S$, etc. as $k$-component vectors $(S_1,\dots,S_k)$, etc. (in which case everything starts to fit together but the problem stops being one about $\mathbb R^4$ dynamics and becomes one about $\mathbb R^{4k}$ dynamics). In other words, your averaged values alone at the moment $0$ are totally insufficient to determine the full dynamics in a unique way.

Comment: I have edited the question.  All variables (S, E, I, R) are positive.

Comment: As I said: your initial conditions involving the averages only *are insufficient* for determining the dynamics, so you have to honestly pose and solve the IVP for a system with $4k$ variables.